# How to avoid runaway threads in apache camel's default task executor?

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I am trying to find out how the apache camel handles the default thread pool with concurrent consumers. Checked the stackoverflow, camel documentation and apache camel in action book but not much information on what is the optimal values being used with the ThreadPool (uses Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with optimal values - cached threadpool-like)

Here is the configuration I used for my application

```
from("jms:queue:test??concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=10&maxMessagesPerTask=-1&defaultTaskExecutorType=ThreadPool &preserveMessageQos=true").inOnly("direct:deliver-normal-route-1");
```

If there any connectivity issues in MQ, I see the thread ID's like 500K+ numbers. Is the cached threadpool create a runaway threads if there is an exception?

To avoid this scenario, I implemented my custom thread pool like,

```
from("jms:queue:test??concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=10&maxMessagesPerTask=-1&taskExecutor=#myTaskExecutor&preserveMessageQos=true").inOnly("direct:deliver-normal-route-1");

<bean id="myTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="myThread" />
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="100" />
        <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="60"></property>
        <property name="awaitTerminationSeconds" value="5" />
        <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown"
            value="true" />
    </bean>
```

With this custom threadpool configuration I don't see any runaway threads. I tested with stopping the MQ channel for few minutes, same threads been resumed and reused unlike the Default threadpool of Camel.

Comment: Have you configured a connection pool for JMS. Usually that is the only thing you need to setup, and then leave it to use the default threading settings and it would run fine as-is.

Comment: @Claus Ibsen Our application is a standalone and we are using the Spring's CachingConnectionFactory to connect to the IBM MQ. When we use the defaultTaskExecutorType=ThreadPool, the threadID is going up all the time. I see a thread ID of 426841 today in the logs. I am able to reproduce this easily by stopping the MQ channel for few mins, the moment I start the channel the thread ID's are very high.